# Is there a way for me to get window.onresize to only refresh the page for width resizes only?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make something like the follow ONLY work if the window width changes (and NOT the height):

```
window.onresize = function(event)
{
   document.location.reload(true);
}
```

I've tried doing some research already, including looking at some answers on here, but whatever I'm doing to adapt the code I've found is not working. How might I go about this?

Comment: Yes, detect whether or not the width changed.

Comment: I did get the jist of that already from the research I've done... but it's not a very helpful answer because I've failed to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
window.onresize = function(event){
    var t = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
    if(t !== x) {
       document.location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This got the job done... also helped me understand what I was doing wrong. Still pretty new to javascript. But I see how to handle something like that now. Thanks!